# Deleting values from Project Preference store

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my custom plugin I am creating some folders on a new Wizard and adding paths of those created folders in project preferences. Now while deleting the folder I need to remove that path from the store. For that I extended `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` extension. I also created a class extending `Change` class and inside it in the perform method I wrote following to remove the key-value from preferences.

```java
public Change perform(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException {
    System.out.println("called");
    IPath deletedFolderPath = deletedFolder.getProjectRelativePath().makeAbsolute();
    IResource[] roots = {deletedFolder.getProject()};
    String[] fileSearchPatterns = {"*.properties", "*.prefs"};
    FileTextSearchScope searchScope = FileTextSearchScope.newSearchScope(roots, fileSearchPatterns, false);

    String regex = deletedFolderPath.addTrailingSeparator().toString();
    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    TextSearchRequestor requestor = new TextSearchRequestor() {

        public boolean acceptPatternMatch(TextSearchMatchAccess matchAccess) throws CoreException {
            IFile matchedFile = matchAccess.getFile();
            if("prefs".equals(matchedFile.getFileExtension())){
                String prefKey = "";
                try {
                    prefKey = ProjectPreferences.getKeyForValue(regex, deletedFolder.getProject());
                    ProjectPreferences.removeKeyFromStore(prefKey, deletedFolder.getProject());
                    System.out.println("after");
                } 
                catch (BackingStoreException e) {
                    throw new CoreException(null);
                }

            }
            else if(".properties".equals(matchedFile.getFileExtension())) {
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    TextSearchEngine.create().search(searchScope, requestor, searchPattern, pm);
    return null;
}
```

but it get stuck on the line after pressing "OK" on the delete wizard.

`ProjectPreferences.removeKeyFromStore(prefKey, deletedFolder.getProject())`

or more specifically on the flush statement written in the `removeKeyFromStore` method

```java
public static void removeKeyFromStore(String key, IProject project) throws BackingStoreException {
    IEclipsePreferences projPref = getPreferences(project);
    projPref.remove(key);
    projPref.flush();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here or any other better way to achieve the same functionality.

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'gets stuck'? What happens?

Comment: On the delete wizard the progress monitor get stuck on "Deleting Resources..". The debugger remains on the flush statement and doesn't return to the `perform` method.